# Comparar extensão de arquivo

Tags: php

Estou tentando comparar a extensão de um arquivo, mas o mesmo está falhando criei uma variável com as extensões permitidas e tento comparar com a que está sendo enviado.

```
// Lista de tipos de arquivos permitidos
$tiposPermitidos = array('gif', 'jpeg', 'jpeg', 'png');

$infos = pathinfo($rowData['imagem']);
$arqType = $infos['extension'];

if (in_array($arqType, $tiposPermitidos)) {             
    echo 'O tipo de arquivo enviado é inválido, permitido somente imagens';
}
```

Executando um `var_dump($infos);` obtenho o seguinte resultado:

```
array(4) { ["dirname"]=> string(9) "../banner" ["basename"]=> string(9) "10889.php" ["extension"]=> string(3) "php" ["filename"]=> string(5) "10889" }
```

Comment: Já verificou o que tem em  `$infos`? Dê um `var_dump($infos)` e inclua o resultado na pergunta.

Comment: A condição está trocada, ele está entrando no `if` com os tipos válidos, não com os inválidos, tente: `if (! in_array($arqType, $tiposPermitidos))`

Comment: Obrigado @gmsantos e bfvaretto pelas excelentes dicas.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A extensão do arquivo nem sempre se refere ao tipo do arquivo, o melhor é detectar o mimetype, por exemplo está função fornece compatibilidade para versões mais antigas do PHP:

```
function mimeType($file)
{
    $mimetype = false;

    if (class_exists('finfo')) {//PHP5.4+
        $finfo     = finfo_open(FILEINFO_MIME_TYPE);
        $mimetype  = finfo_file($finfo, $file);
        finfo_close($finfo);
    } else if (function_exists('mime_content_type')) {//php5.3 ou inferiror
        $mimetype = mime_content_type($file);
    }

    return $mimetype;
}
```

Usando:

```
$infos = mimeType($rowData['imagem']);

if (strpos($infos, 'image/') !== 0) {
    echo 'O tipo de arquivo enviado é inválido, permitido somente imagens';
}
```

No primeiro exemplo ele vai aceitar qualquer tipo de imagem, por exemplo SVG, no entanto se quiser limitar, você pode criar uma array/vetor:

```
$permitidos = array(
    'jpeg', 'png', 'gif'
);

$infos = mimeType($rowData['imagem']);

//Transforma image/jpeg em jpeg por exemplo
$infos = str_replace('image/', '', $infos);

//Remove content-types experimentais, como icon/x-icon (eu não sei se a API do php reconhece content-types experimentais, é apenas por garantia)
$infos = str_replace('x-', '', $infos);

if (false === in_array($infos, $permitidos)) {
    echo 'O tipo de arquivo enviado é inválido, permitido somente imagens';
}
```