# download de arquivo em mysql

Tags: php, mysql

Tenho arquivos em meu banco de dados que gostaria de disponibilizar para download.
Esses arquivos são de diversas extensões; .pdf, .txt, doc, .xlxs e etc;

Procurei em muito lugares mas não encontrei nada detalhado (para iniciantes).

Quero fazer uma lista dos arquivos que tem em meu banco e gerar um link para download.

Comment: Como é a tabela no banco de dados? Ele contem uma referência aonde o arquivo está, ou literalmente o arquivo está dentro do banco de dados? (exemplo, é uma *path*, tipo `C:\arquivos\teste.pdf`?)

Comment: o arquivo esta dentro da pasta upload e o caminho no banco de dados está uploads/nome-do-arquivo.extensao

Comment: @RafaelAcioly, poste a parte que esta em dificuldade para que possamos lhe ajudar, mostre como está vindo as informações para a view.

Comment: @RafaelAcioly, é só vc fazer um select * from tabela no mysql, depois faz um foreach nos dados e um echo na pasta  e nome dos arquivos. Tem isso detalhado no meu site: http://www.tocadigital.com.br

Comment: Conseguiu resolver o problema Rafael?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Diretório publico

A pasta `./upload` sendo "publica" então poderemos acessar seus arquivos, os arquivos sendo estáticos basta listar os dados do mysql e criar um `.htacces` na pasta `./upload` para forçar o download de arquivos nesta tal pasta, por exemplo:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `arquivos` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `path` varchar(800) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

O `SELECT` ficaria algo como:

```
<?php
$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "my_user", "my_password", "world");

if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
    exit;
}

$query = 'SELECT path FROM `arquivos`';

if ($result = $mysqli->query($query)) {
    while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        echo '<a href="', $row['path'],
             '">Download de ', basename($row['path']),
             '</a>';
    }

    $result->close();
}

$mysqli->close();
```

`.htaccess` deve ficar na mesma pasta que os arquivos:

```
<FilesMatch "\.(?i:mov|mp3|jpg|pdf)$"> #altere nesta linha os tipos de arquivos
ForceType application/octet-stream
Header set Content-Disposition attachment
</FilesMatch>
```

No entanto se não tiver acesso ou não usar apache pode-se tentar o atributo `download=""`, ficaria algo como:

```
$query = 'SELECT path FROM `arquivos`';

if ($result = $mysqli->query($query)) {
    while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        $nome = basename($row['path']);

        echo '<a download="', $nome,'" href="', $row['path'],
             '">Download de ', $nome,
             '</a>';
    }

    $result->close();
}

$mysqli->close();
```

### Diretorio privativo

Se você não quer permitir acesso direto ao diretório ou não tem como acessar pois ele não se encontra dentro da pasta do servidor será necessário talvez criar um php ou uma rota com .htaccess,

Supondo (hipotético) que os arquivos do servidor estejam em `/etc/var/www` (ou no windows `c:/www`) e os arquivos para download em `/home/user/upload` (ou no windows `c:/upload`) então você deve criar um .php assim:

```
$query = 'SELECT path FROM `arquivos`';

if ($result = $mysqli->query($query)) {
    while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        $nome = basename($row['path']);

        echo '<a href="download.php?file=', urlencode($nome),
             '">Download de ', $nome,
             '</a>';
    }

    $result->close();
}

$mysqli->close();
```

e o arquivo download.php deve ser algo como:

> Usando trecho desta resposta https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/73497/3635

```
<?php
$nome = isset($_GET['file']) ? $_GET['file'] : null;
$fullPath = '/home/user/upload/' . $nome;

if ($nome === null) {
    echo 'Parametro file não definido';
    exit;
} else if (false === is_file($fullPath)) {
    echo 'Arquivo não encontrado';
    exit;
}

function mimeType($file) {
    $mimetype = false;

    if (class_exists('finfo')) {//PHP5.4+
        $finfo     = finfo_open(FILEINFO_MIME_TYPE);
        $mimetype  = finfo_file($finfo, $file);
        finfo_close($finfo);
    } else if (function_exists('mime_content_type')) {//php5.3 ou inferiror
        $mimetype = mime_content_type($file);
    }

    return $mimetype;
}

$mime = mimeType($fullPath);

if ($mime === false) {
    echo 'Não foi possível detectar o tipo de arquivo';
    exit;
}

header('Content-type: ' . $mime);

//Seta o tamanho do arquivo
header('Content-length: ' . filesize($fullPath));

//Força o download
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=' . $nome);

//Este header é necessário
header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');

echo file_get_contents($fullPath, FILE_BINARY);
```

Answer (score 0):

Técnicamente é simples, você só precisaria dar um request no DB e fazer um while escrevendo:

```
<a href="<? echo $row[link_conteudo']?>"><? echo $row[titulo']?></a>
```