# Adicionar mais de uma imagem no PDF usando o mpdf

Tags: php, html, upload, imagem

Preciso gerar um PDF com a classe MPDF  dentro do PDF precisa conter algumas imagens, que serão enviadas através da pagina form.html, que envia as imagens para gera-pdf.php que processa e converte o conteúdo para PDF

form.html

```
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="gera-pdf.php">
Selecione uma imagem: <input name="arquivo" type="file" />
<br />
<input type="submit" value="Gerar PDF" />
</form>
```

gera-pdf.php

```
  <?php
 ob_start(); //inicia o buffer
?>

 <!--COMEÇA CONTEUDO DO PDF-->




 <!--TERMINA CONTEUDO DO PDF-->


<?php
 $html = ob_get_clean();
// pega o conteudo do buffer, insere na variavel e limpa a memória

$html = utf8_encode($html);
// converte o conteudo para uft-8


include("mpdf60/mpdf.php");
// inclui a classe


$mpdf = new mPDF();
// cria o objeto

$mpdf->allow_charset_conversion=true;
// permite a conversao (opcional)
$mpdf->charset_in='UTF-8';
// converte todo o PDF para utf-8

$mpdf->WriteHTML($html);
// escreve definitivamente o conteudo no PDF

$mpdf->Output();
// imprime

exit();
// finaliza o codigo

?>
```

Código que recebe o upload

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Upload de arquivos</title>
</head>

<body>
<?php
// verifica se foi enviado um arquivo 
if(isset($_FILES['arquivo']['name']) && $_FILES["arquivo"]["error"] == 0)
{

  echo "Você enviou o arquivo: <strong>" . $_FILES['arquivo']['name'] . "      </strong><br />";
echo "Este arquivo é do tipo: <strong>" . $_FILES['arquivo']['type'] . "</strong><br />";
echo "Temporáriamente foi salvo em: <strong>" . $_FILES['arquivo']['tmp_name'] . "</strong><br />";
echo "Seu tamanho é: <strong>" . $_FILES['arquivo']['size'] . "</strong> Bytes<br /><br />";

$arquivo_tmp = $_FILES['arquivo']['tmp_name'];
$nome = $_FILES['arquivo']['name'];


// Pega a extensao
$extensao = strrchr($nome, '.');

// Converte a extensao para mimusculo
$extensao = strtolower($extensao);

// Somente imagens, .jpg;.jpeg;.gif;.png
// Aqui eu enfilero as extesões permitidas e separo por ';'
// Isso server apenas para eu poder pesquisar dentro desta String
if(strstr('.jpg;.jpeg;.gif;.png', $extensao))
{
    // Cria um nome único para esta imagem
    // Evita que duplique as imagens no servidor.
    $novoNome = md5(microtime()) . $extensao;

    // Concatena a pasta com o nome
    $destino = 'imagens/' . $novoNome; 

    // tenta mover o arquivo para o destino
    if( @move_uploaded_file( $arquivo_tmp, $destino  ))
    {
        echo "Arquivo salvo com sucesso em : <strong>" . $destino . "</strong><br />";
        echo "<img src=\"" . $destino . "\" />";
    }
    else
        echo "Erro ao salvar o arquivo. Aparentemente você não tem permissão de escrita.<br />";
}
else
    echo "Você poderá enviar apenas arquivos \"*.jpg;*.jpeg;*.gif;*.png\"<br />";
 }
 else
 {
   echo "Você não enviou nenhum arquivo!";
 }
?>
</body>
</html>
```

Dentro de "COMECA CONTEUDO PDF" do código gera-pdf.php eu coloquei o código que recebe o upload (no caso a imagem)
como mostrado abaixo.

quando eu clico em GERAR PDF na pagina form.html
ele chama a pagina gera-pdf.php, que já abre um PDF com a imagem, porem é possível enviar somente uma imagem, e eu queria enviar mais de uma imagem

> > > Segue o link com os arquivos no dropbox para maior compreensão https://www.dropbox.com/s/h7pfvgyl7v1xvug/gera-pdf.zip?dl=0

```
      <?php
 ob_start(); //inicia o buffer
?>

 <!--COMEÇA CONTEUDO DO PDF-->



 <!DOCTYPE html>
 <html>
 <head>
 <meta charset="utf-8" />
 <title>Upload de arquivos</title>
</head>

<body>
<?php
// verifica se foi enviado um arquivo 
if(isset($_FILES['arquivo']['name']) && $_FILES["arquivo"]["error"] == 0)
{

 echo "Você enviou o arquivo: <strong>" . $_FILES['arquivo']['name'] . "    </strong><br />";
echo "Este arquivo é do tipo: <strong>" . $_FILES['arquivo']['type'] . "</strong><br />";
echo "Temporáriamente foi salvo em: <strong>" . $_FILES['arquivo']['tmp_name'] . "</strong><br />";
echo "Seu tamanho é: <strong>" . $_FILES['arquivo']['size'] . "</strong> Bytes<br /><br />";

$arquivo_tmp = $_FILES['arquivo']['tmp_name'];
$nome = $_FILES['arquivo']['name'];


// Pega a extensao
$extensao = strrchr($nome, '.');

// Converte a extensao para mimusculo
$extensao = strtolower($extensao);

 // Somente imagens, .jpg;.jpeg;.gif;.png
 // Aqui eu enfilero as extesões permitidas e separo por ';'
 // Isso server apenas para eu poder pesquisar dentro desta String
 if(strstr('.jpg;.jpeg;.gif;.png', $extensao))
 {
    // Cria um nome único para esta imagem
    // Evita que duplique as imagens no servidor.
    $novoNome = md5(microtime()) . $extensao;

    // Concatena a pasta com o nome
    $destino = 'imagens/' . $novoNome; 

    // tenta mover o arquivo para o destino
    if( @move_uploaded_file( $arquivo_tmp, $destino  ))
    {
        echo "Arquivo salvo com sucesso em : <strong>" . $destino . "</strong><br />";
        echo "<img src=\"" . $destino . "\" />";
    }
    else
        echo "Erro ao salvar o arquivo. Aparentemente você não tem permissão de escrita.<br />";
}
else
    echo "Você poderá enviar apenas arquivos \"*.jpg;*.jpeg;*.gif;*.png\"<br />";
}
else
{
  echo "Você não enviou nenhum arquivo!";
}
?>
</body>
</html>



   <!--TERMINA CONTEUDO DO PDF-->


  <?php
  $html = ob_get_clean();
  // pega o conteudo do buffer, insere na variavel e limpa a memória

  $html = utf8_encode($html);
  // converte o conteudo para uft-8


   include("mpdf60/mpdf.php");
   // inclui a classe


   $mpdf = new mPDF();
   // cria o objeto

   $mpdf->allow_charset_conversion=true;
  // permite a conversao (opcional)
  $mpdf->charset_in='UTF-8';
  // converte todo o PDF para utf-8

  $mpdf->WriteHTML($html);
  // escreve definitivamente o conteudo no PDF

  $mpdf->Output();
 // imprime

exit();
// finaliza o codigo

?>
```

Comment: Por favor evitem longas discussões nos comentários; a conversa de vocês foi [movida para o chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/30444/discussion-on-question-by-wender-adicionar-mais-de-uma-imagem-no-pdf-usando-o-mp)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Me parece que o teu problema nem de perto é com:

> porem é possível enviar somente uma imagem, e eu queria enviar mais de uma imagem

A maneira que você fez o *upload* é o que lhe permite enviar apenas uma imagem, eu não vou entrar muito em detalhes, mas existe uma série de falhas no seu código e eu realmente recomendo estudar um pouco mais PHP, porque a falha é mais no uso do php do que nas classes que esta usando, como a omissão do `{` após o `else` com uma indentação que causará conflitos no interpretador do PHP e você deixou espaços antes.

### Fazendo múltiplo upload usando a marcação HTML

Pra fazer upload de múltiplos arquivos você pode usar `[]` no html que permite trabalhar com um vetor, por exemplo:

```
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="gera-pdf.php">

Imagem 1: <input name="arquivo[]" type="file" />
Imagem 2: <input name="arquivo[]" type="file" />
Imagem 3: <input name="arquivo[]" type="file" />
Imagem 4: <input name="arquivo[]" type="file" />
Imagem 5: <input name="arquivo[]" type="file" />

<br />
<input type="submit" value="Gerar PDF" />
</form>
```

Antes de partir pro PHP veja estes detalhes:

- Eu não tenho certeza mas acho que as tags `<html>` e `body` são dispensáveis no mPDF.
- O `strrchr($nome, '.');` não verifica o tipo real da imagem, ele só verifica a extensão, ou seja um arquivo pode usar a extensão .jpg mas pode ser um arquivo de texto o que pode ocasionar falhas no teu script, **leia isto** https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/73497/3635

O php deve ficar algo como:

```
<?php
ob_start();

function mimeType($file)
{
    $mimetype = false;

    if (class_exists('finfo')) {//PHP5.4+
        $finfo    = finfo_open(FILEINFO_MIME_TYPE);
        $mimetype = finfo_file($finfo, $file);
        finfo_close($finfo);
    } else if (function_exists('mime_content_type')) {//php5.3 ou inferiror
        $mimetype = mime_content_type($file);
    } else {
        echo 'Habilite o php_fileinfo.dll (ou fileinfo.so) no php.ini e reiniciei o servidor';
        exit;
    }

    return $mimetype;
}

function upload($current)
{
    $arquivo_tmp = $_FILES['arquivo']['tmp_name'][$current];
    $nome = $_FILES['arquivo']['name'][$current];

    echo "Você enviou o arquivo: <strong>" . $nome . " </strong><br />";
    echo "Este arquivo é do tipo: <strong>" . $_FILES['arquivo']['type'][$current] . "</strong><br />";
    echo "Temporáriamente foi salvo em: <strong>" . $arquivo_tmp . "</strong><br />";
    echo "Seu tamanho é: <strong>" . $_FILES['arquivo']['size'][$current] . "</strong> Bytes<br /><br />";

    $permitidos = array(//Não é necessário jpg pois pro mime-types só existe image/jpeg
        'jpeg', 'png', 'gif'
    );

    //Detecta o mime-type
    $infos = mimeType($arquivo_tmp);

    //Transforma image/jpeg em jpeg por exemplo
    $infos = str_replace('image/', '', $infos);

    //Remove content-types experimentais, como icon/x-icon
    // (eu não sei se a API do php reconhece content-types experimentais,
    // é apenas por garantia)
    $infos = str_replace('x-', '', $infos);

    if(in_array($infos, $permitidos))
    {
        // Cria um nome único para esta imagem
        // Evita que duplique as imagens no servidor.
        // $current é usado pra evitar que todas fotos usem o mesmo nome
        // Usando a informação extraida do mime-type como extensão
        $novoNome = md5(microtime()) . '-' . $current . '.' . $infos;

        // Concatena a pasta com o nome
        $destino = 'imagens/' . $novoNome; 

        // tenta mover o arquivo para o destino
        if(move_uploaded_file($arquivo_tmp, $destino))
        {
            echo "Arquivo salvo com sucesso em : <strong>" . $destino . "</strong><br />";
            echo "<img src=\"" . $destino . "\" />";
        }
        else
        {
            echo "Erro ao salvar o arquivo. Aparentemente você não tem permissão de escrita.<br />";
            exit;//Previne gerar o pdf
        }
    }
    else
    {
        echo "Você poderá enviar apenas arquivos \"*.jpg;*.jpeg;*.gif;*.png\"<br />";
        exit;//Previne gerar o pdf
    }
}

$files = $_FILES["arquivo"]["error"];
$i = 0;
$j = 0;

foreach ($files as $key => $error)
{
    if ($error == UPLOAD_ERR_OK)
    {
        upload($i);
    }
    else if ($error == UPLOAD_ERR_NO_FILE)
    {
        ++$j;
    }
    else
    {
        echo "Erro ao enviar um dos arquivos";
        exit; //previne gerar pdf se houver erros no upload
    }
    ++$i;
}

//Compara a quantidade de arquivos que foram enviados com a quantidade campos "não vazios"
if ($j === $i) {
    echo 'Selecione ao menos um arquivo de foto';
    exit;
}

$html = ob_get_clean();
// pega o conteudo do buffer, insere na variavel e limpa a memória

echo $html = utf8_encode($html);
// converte o conteudo para uft-8

include "mpdf60/mpdf.php";
// inclui a classe

$mpdf = new mPDF();
// cria o objeto

$mpdf->allow_charset_conversion = true;
// permite a conversao (opcional)
$mpdf->charset_in='UTF-8';
// converte todo o PDF para utf-8

$mpdf->WriteHTML($html);
// escreve definitivamente o conteudo no PDF

$mpdf->Output();
//Não necessita de exit no final apenas OMITA o "?>" pra não gerar espaços no final do arquivo
```

### Depurando o mPDF

Se tiver problemas com o mPDF use o `$mpdf->debug = true;`, assim:

```
$mpdf = new mPDF();

$mpdf->debug = true;

$mpdf->allow_charset_conversion = true;
$mpdf->charset_in='UTF-8';
```

Também pode tentar o `showImageErrors`, assim:

```
$mpdf = new mPDF();

$mpdf->showImageErrors = true;

$mpdf->allow_charset_conversion = true;
$mpdf->charset_in='UTF-8';
```

### Constantes no PHP pra upload

- **UPLOAD_ERR_OK**

  Valor: 0; não houve erro, o upload foi bem sucedido.
- **UPLOAD_ERR_INI_SIZE**

  Valor 1; O arquivo enviado excede o limite definido na diretiva `upload_max_filesize` do *php.ini*
- **UPLOAD_ERR_FORM_SIZE**

  Valor: 2; O arquivo excede o limite definido em MAX_FILE_SIZE no formulário HTML.
- **UPLOAD_ERR_PARTIAL**

  Valor: 3; O upload do arquivo foi feito parcialmente.
- **UPLOAD_ERR_NO_FILE**

  Valor: 4; Nenhum arquivo foi enviado.
- **UPLOAD_ERR_NO_TMP_DIR**

  Valor: 6; Pasta temporária ausente. Introduzido no PHP 5.0.3.
- **UPLOAD_ERR_CANT_WRITE**

  Valor: 7; Falha em escrever o arquivo em disco. Introduzido no PHP 5.1.0.
- **UPLOAD_ERR_EXTENSION**

  Valor: 8; Uma extensão do PHP interrompeu o upload do arquivo. O PHP não fornece uma maneira de determinar qual extensão causou a interrupção. Examinar a lista das extensões carregadas com o `phpinfo()` pode ajudar. Introduzido no PHP 5.2.0.

<sub>Documentação php: http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/features.file-upload.errors.php</sub>

Comment: Para múltiplos ficheiros, basta que se coloque um atributo `name="arquivo[]"` seguindo de um atributo `multiple`, é igualmente funcional.