# Colocar uma imagem no centro de outra imagem em PHP

Tags: php, imagem, gd

Eu tenho uma imagem .png de por exemplo 200x200px.

Eu preciso que ela fique com 300x300px, mas sem aumentar a imagem, apenas colocando ela dentro e centralizada em um quadrado branco de 300x300px.

Isso é possível? Como eu posso fazer para centralizar essa imagem?

Lembrando que eu preciso fazer isso no lado do servidor, usando a biblioteca de imagens do PHP.

Obrigado.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Acredito que esteja tentando fazer isso através de formulário para envio da imagem, então elaborei uma resposta pensando nisso.

```
<form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="file" name="img" />
    <input type="submit" name="ok" value="Enviar" />
</form>

<?php

$tempname = $_FILES["img"]["tmp_name"]; // Caminho completo da imagem original.
$extension = strtolower(pathinfo($_FILES["img"]["name"], PATHINFO_EXTENSION)); // Extraindo extensão com 'pathinfo' da imagem original.
$name = "new_img"; // Nome do novo arquivo de imagem
$url = "images/".$name.".".$extension; // Caminho onde será salvo a nova imagem
$max_width = 300; // Largura final da imagem
$max_height = 300; // Altura final da imagem

$allowed_extensions = array('gif', 'jpg', 'png'); // Extensões permitidas

if(in_array($extension, $allowed_extensions)) { // Se extensão é permitida...
    move_uploaded_file($tempname, $url); // Move para o caminho definido em '$url'
} else return "Arquivo não permitido.";

// Pega a largura, altura, tipo e atributo da imagem
list($image_width, $image_height, $type, $attribute) = getimagesize($url);

// Calcula o coeficiente para centralização
$x = round(($max_width - $image_width) / 2);
$y = round(($max_height - $image_height) / 2);                                            

// Cria uma nova imagem com o novo tamanho
$new_image = imagecreatetruecolor($max_width, $max_height);

// Define o background desta nova imagem (RGB), neste caso, 'branco' como precisa.
$bg = imagecolorallocate($new_image, 255, 255, 255);
imagefill($new_image, 0, 0, $bg);

switch ($type){
    case 1: // Se a imagem for GIF...
        $source = imagecreatefromgif($url); // Pega a imagem original GIF
        imagecopyresampled($new_image, $source, $x, $y, 0, 0, $image_width, $image_height, $image_width, $image_height); 
        imagegif($new_image, $url); // Gera a nova imagem sobrescrevendo a original
        break;
    case 2: // Se a imagem for JPG...
        $source = imagecreatefromjpeg($url); // Pega a imagem original JPG
        imagecopyresampled($new_image, $source, $x, $y, 0, 0, $image_width, $image_height, $image_width, $image_height);
        imagejpeg($new_image, $url, 70); // Gera a nova imagem sobrescrevendo a original (com resolução de 70 (vai de 0 à 100))
        break;
    case 3: // Se a imagem for PNG...
        $source = imagecreatefrompng($url); // Pega a imagem original PNG
        imagecopyresampled($new_image, $source, $x, $y, 0, 0, $image_width, $image_height, $image_width, $image_height);
        imagepng($new_image, $url, 9); // Gera a nova imagem sobrescrevendo a original (com compactação de 9 (vai de 0 à 9))
        break;
}

// Destrói as imagens criadas
imagedestroy($new_image);
imagedestroy($source);
```

Só não coloquei comentário para a função `imagecopyresampled()`, achei melhor postar esta leitura sugerida:

> http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagecopyresampled.php

Comment: Muito obrigado. Na verdade não era por meio de um form mas resolveu do mesmo jeito. Eu sabia dessas outras funções, o que eu precisava era dessa função round. Muito obrigado novamente.

Comment: **[editado]** Uma dica Thyago e @JuniorZancan este método de verificar extensão não é seguro, recomendo que leiam: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/73497/3635

Comment: Obrigado @GuilhermeNascimento, mas o script que eu estou usando já faz a verificação da extensão e não apenas pelo nome. Então desse script ai eu só usei a parte do "round".

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento, muito obrigado pela dica, não tinha conhecimento, pelo visto corro risco até mesmo de receber um executável apenas com a extensão editada para png! =)

Answer (score 2):

Você pode usar [`imagecopymerge`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagecopymerge.php) pra isto, como descrito na documentação:

```
bool imagecopymerge ( resource $dst_im , resource $src_im , int $dst_x ,
                        int $dst_y , int $src_x , int $src_y , int $src_w ,
                           int $src_h , int $pct )
```

Veja um exemplo, leia os comentários dentro do código:

```
<?php
$dest       = imagecreatefromjpeg('foto.jpg'); //Pega a imagem principal
$marcadagua = imagecreatefromgif('marcadagua.gif'); //Pega a imagem que vai ser centralizada

//pega o tamanho da imagem principal
$dwidth  = imagesx($dest);
$dheight = imagesy($dest);

//pega o tamanho da imagem que vai ser centralizada
$mwidth  = imagesx($marcadagua);
$mheight = imagesy($marcadagua);

//Calcula a x e y posição pra colocar a imagem no centro da outra
//A função round arredonda os valores
$xPos = round(($dwidth  - $mwidth)  / 2);
$yPos = round(($dheight - $mheight) / 2);

imagecopymerge($dest, $marcadagua, $xPos, $yPos, 0, 0, $mwidth, $mheight, 100);

header('Content-Type: image/jpeg');
imagejpeg($dest);

//destrói resources 
imagedestroy($dest);
imagedestroy($marcadagua);
```

Você pode alterar o ultimo argumento pra obter deixar a imagem menos opaca, ou seja um pouco transparente, por exemplo, se fizer isto a imagem centralizada irá ficar um pouco apagada:

```
imagecopymerge($dest, $marcadagua, $xPos, $yPos, 0, 0, $mwidth, $mheight, 70);
```

Answer (score 0):

A maneira mais fácil é sobrepor uma imagem na outra, crie uma imagem branca 300x300 para servir de base, gosto bastante de usar a biblioteca [WideImage](http://wideimage.sourceforge.net/), é leve e sem muitas complicações, segue o exemplo:

```
<?php
    require_once('lib/WideImage.php');
    $base = WideImage::load('white.jpg'); // carregue sua base
    $imagem = WideImage::load('imagem.jpg'); // carregue sua imagem

    $base->merge($imagem, 50, 50, 100)->saveToFile('resultado.jpg'); // faça o merge

?>
```

o Exemplo é bem intuitivo, para mais informações acesso o site e a documentação.

Espero que ajude, abraços.

Comment: Mas nesse caso a imagem original teria que ser 200x200px, não poderia ser de um tamanho dinâmico, correto?