# Pesquisando na variável letras apos o ponto para validar upload no Dropzone

Tags: javascript, dropzonejs

Estou com um problema, na verdade estou desenvolvendo um sistema de upload de imagem e estou utilizando o [dropzone](http://www.dropzonejs.com), porém preciso fazer algo para separar os arquivos que tenho, na real posso aceitar apenas imagens do tipo jpeg, png, jpg. Para isto estou pegando o nome do arquivo enviado exemplo: `blablabla.jpeg` preciso pegar tudo depois do ponto ou seja preciso que retorne para mim, `jpeg`. Assim faço um case, e se caso não for o que deixo fazer upload eu cancelo.

Como fazer isto (pegar tudo depois do . `!ponto`) em javascript?

Ou o sistema mesmo do dropzone teria como resolver isto ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Se for para pegar a extensão de um arquivo lembre-se nomes podem ter ponto antes da extensão o que vai fazer o teu script (https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/112999/3635) falhar.

Você pode fazer desta maneira:

```js
var v = "ARQUIVO.1.2.3.4.PNG";
var splt = v.split(".");

document.getElementById("nome").innerHTML = v;
document.getElementById("extensao").innerHTML = splt[splt.length - 1];
```

```html
<div id="nome"></div>
<div id="extensao"></div>
```

Se quiser remover a extensão do nome pode usar *regex* com `.match`:

```js
var v = "ARQUIVO.1.2.3.4.PNG";
var splt = v.match(/(.*?)\.([a-zA-Z0-9]+)$/);

document.getElementById("nomecompleto").innerHTML = splt[0];
document.getElementById("nome").innerHTML         = splt[1];
document.getElementById("extensao").innerHTML     = splt[2];
```

```html
<div id="nomecompleto"></div>
<div id="nome"></div>
<div id="extensao"></div>
```

### Usando o back-end

Mas preste muita atenção, este tipo de checagem não é segura, qualquer um pode renomear um arquivo para uma extensão invalida. Não sei qual linguagem vai usar, mas o melhor é verificar o mimetype, por exemplo:

- [Comparar extensão de arquivo](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/73497/3635)

### Usando o Dropzone.js

Como você está usando o `Dropzone.js` criar um javascript para isto é totalmente desnecessário, o proprio dropzone tem a opção de validação, veja a documentação http://www.dropzonejs.com/#config-acceptedFiles

Use assim para aceitar somente .jpg, .jpeg e .png (não sei se a checagem é segura ou é feita por mimetype, todavia cria a checagem do lado do servidor como dito anteriormente):

```
var myDropzone = new Dropzone("#meuid", {
    url: "URL",
    acceptedFiles: "image/jpeg,image/png"
});
```

Somente JPG:

```
var myDropzone = new Dropzone("#meuid", {
    url: "URL",
    acceptedFiles: "image/jpeg"
});
```

Ou assim para todos tipos de imagens:

```
var myDropzone = new Dropzone("#meuid", {
    url: "URL",
    acceptedFiles: "image/*"
});
```

Comment: Muito boa resposta, teria como me ajudar em algumas outras configurações. porque estou tendo problema ao definir os tipos como exemplificado, em minha div so está descrito seguinte: `                                <div class="x_content">
                                    <form action="bb" class="dropzone" style="border: 1px solid #e5e5e5; height: 300px; "></form>
                                </div>` O restante e dinâmico, baseado nisto como vou definir os tipos de arquivos ?

Comment: @RenanRodrigues como esta o Javascript?

Comment: <script>
    var myDropzone = new Dropzone(".x_content", {
    url: "URL",
    acceptedFiles: "image/*"
});
</script>

Comment: @RenanRodrigues Tentou fazer assim `var myDropzone = new Dropzone(".x_content", { url: "URL", acceptedFiles: "image/jpeg" });`??

Comment: sim desta forma mesmo

Comment: @RenanRodrigues mas não esta funcionando? Ele não esta filtrando os arquivos?

Answer (score 1):

Encontrei a solução, bastou fazer

```
var split = varivel.split(".");
```

depois para aparecer tudo que tiver depois do ponto fiz:

```
split[1]
```

Abaixo um exemplo de como utilizar.

```js
var v = "ARQUIVO.PNG";
var splt = v.split(".");

$(".anterioro").html(v);
$(".posterior").html(splt[1]);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="anterioro"></div>
<div class="posterior"></div>
```