# Como Validar apenas Jpeg como extensão para upload de arquivos?

Tags: php, laravel

Sou iniciante na programação.

```
    public function upload(){

    if(Input::hasFile('file')){
        $novonome = uniqid() . '.jpeg';
        $file = Input::file('file');
        $file->move('uploads',$novonome);
        return 'Anexado com sucesso';
    }

    if(UploadedFile::getMaxFilesize()){
        return "Limite máximo de 2 mb";
        }  
    }
```

Comment: Qual versão do Laravel amigo?

Comment: @Leandro Versão 5.2

Comment: tem falando sobre isso na doc da 5.2 http://api.symfony.com/3.0/Symfony/Component/HttpFoundation/File/UploadedFile.html#method_getClientOriginalExtension

Comment: @Leandro, Eu cheguei a olhar, mas não entendi como utilizar de forma correta, teria como demonstrar a utilização do Symfony  baseado no problema acima ?

Comment: `$extension = File::extension($filename);`

Comment: @Leandro, putz vei ainda estou com dúvidas para utilizar esse File::extension no meu código !

Comment: Caleb eu respondi com alguns detalhes e exemplos.

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento Putz cara muito obrigado pela força ! Sou iniciante na programação, então as vezes fico batendo cabeça em pequenas coisas ! Com sua explicação deu pra entender o funcionamento do mime certinho ! Valeu muito obrigado !

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento Me tira uma dúvida, como eu faria para realizar a verificação da extensão fileinfo via código php ? Pois eu precisaria rodar esse código em outra máquina aí ele me daria o retorno se a extensão está ativa ou não. Aí eu utilizaria outro código sem ser utilizando mime type de maneira bem fraca mesmo, para fazer  a comparação de extensão. Se puder ajudar estaria muito grato !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A validação por extensão de arquivo não é segura, este link não contem a resposta pra "Laravel" (apesar de poder funcionar) mas explica o problema que as validações por extensão podem causar:

- [Comparar extensão de arquivo](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/73497/3635)

O preferível é validar via mimeType, pra isto use assim:

```
if(Input::hasFile('file')){
    $file = Input::file('file');

    if($file->getMimeType() === 'image/jpeg') {
        $novonome = uniqid() . '.jpeg';

        $file->move('uploads',$novonome);

        return 'Anexado com sucesso';
    }

    return 'Só é permitido imagens JPEG';
}
```

o `getMimeType()` pega o mimeType do arquivo ao invés da extensão, porque como eu disse aqui a extensão pode não ser de um arquivo válido.

Também pode usar a classe `Request` + `Validation`, e um detalhe, esse método que usou `UploadedFile::getMaxFilesize()` não é pra validar, é só pra saber o limite que é possivel fazer de upload variando com as configurações do PHP, use o `Validator` pra limitar o peso do arquivo.

```
public function upload(Request $req)
{
    //Verifica se o campo veio vazio
    if (!$file->hasFile('file')) {
        return 'Não foi enviado a foto';
    }

    //Pega o arquivo
    $file = $request->file('file');

    $input = [
      'file' => $file
    ];


    /*
     * Regras da validação, como mimetype e tamanho máximo
     * 2048 é igual a 2mb, altere conforme a necessidade
     */
    $rules = [
      'file' => 'image|mimes:jpeg|max:2048'
    ];

    $messages = [
      'mimes' => 'Formato invalido'
    ];

    $validator = Validator::make($input, $rules, $messages);

    if ($validator->fails()) {
        return $validator->messages();
    }

    $novonome = uniqid() . '.jpeg';

    $file->move('uploads', $novonome);

    return 'Anexado com sucesso';
}
```

### Habilitando fileinfo

Pra habilitar o fileinfo é necessário editar o php.ini e descomentar esta linha:

```
;extension=php_fileinfo.dll
```

Deixando assim:

```
extension=php_fileinfo.dll
```

Após isto reinicie o Apache ou Ngnix (ou qualquer que seja o seu servidor)

Answer (score 1):

O método de validação aceita um requisição **HTTP** de entrada em conjunto com suas regras de validação, se suas regras de validação passar seu código irá ser executado normalmente caso ao contrario, irá enviar um resposta de erro.

Como no código abaixo:

```
$validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
   'image' => 'mimes:jpeg'
];

    if( $validator->fails() ) {
        return $validator->messages();
    }
```

Se os parâmetros de solicitação de entrada não passar, o Laravel automaticamente vai redirecionar o usuário para sua posição anterior com todos os erros atualizados pela sessão.

Para mostrar esses erros na **view**, podemos utilizar o código abaixo:

```
@if (count($errors) > 0)
    <div class="alert alert-danger">
        <ul>
            @foreach ($errors->all() as $error)
                <li>{{ $error }}</li>
            @endforeach
        </ul>
    </div>
@endif
```

Esse código basicamente vai contar os erros, caso esses erros existirem vai mostrar para o usuário final.

Comment: Poderia explicar o código?

Comment: Na variavel validator estou recuperando todos os campos do form, disse que no campo image só pode ser aceito imagens do tipo jpg, depois fiz uma condição, se existir erro, retorna a mensagem do erro.

Comment: Acho que não entendeu, tudo bem; veja assim, a sua resposta é a melhor, pois eu entendo um pouco de Laravel e bastante de php e mimetypes, mas apenas código na resposta torna ela de baixa qualidade, o legal é explicar como funciona o mimetype e um pouco da classe `Validator`, bem básico, não precisa ser nada muito detalhado, recomendo que siga o exemplo de outras repostas que tem pontuação alta, entenda como uma critica construtiva.

Comment: Sou novo aqui no Stack, pesso perdão por não ter seguido as regras de como responder adequadamente, vou me aprofundar mais e ver como que eu faço uma respostade qualidade. Muito obrigado pelo aviso.

Comment: @ThePrince está dando o seguinte erro: Unable to guess the mime type as no guessers are available (Did you enable the php_fileinfo extension?). Sou iniciante na programação se der pra vc detalhar pra min uma resposta seria ótimo e de grande ajuda.

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento Poderia me ajudar como realizar essa comparação para apenas validar imagens do tipo jpeg ? Sou iniciante

Comment: A parte do php_fileinfo extension, você tem que ativar no seu php, este link vai te ensinar de como fazer isso https://community.xibo.org.uk/t/how-do-i-enable-fileinfo-in-php/78. E uma pergunta, você é iniciante no php ou no laravel?

Comment: @Caleb que estranho por padrão no PHP5.5 esta extensão deveria estar habilitada.

Comment: @ThePrince, poderia editar sua resposta? Como dito peloa Guilherme, se não melhorar, sua resposta corre o risco de ser invalidada! Obrigado pela compreensão!

Comment: Tentei arrumar do melhor jeito possível, como disse anteriormente, sou novo aqui e não sabia como funcionava, peço perdão pelo o que aconteceu e isso não vai se repetir mais.