# Como verificar se a extensão php_fileinfo.dll está ativa ou não via código php?

Tags: php, extensão

Eu precisaria rodar esse código em outra máquina, caso a extensão:

```
extension=php_fileinfo.dll
```

Preciso dela pra utilização do **mimetype**, acaso esteja desativada eu utilizaria outro código sem ser utilizando **mimetype** para fazer a comparação de extensão.

Comment: Você quer verificar ou quer ativar?

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento A princípio queria realizar a verificação, pois não sei é possível realizar a ativação via código, então poderia ser os dois.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Além do `extension_loaded` citado você pode usar `function_exits` pra verificar se a função esta disponível (seria como um *"feature detection"*), você pode fazer assim no script:

```
if (!function_exits('finfo_file')) {
   echo 'Extensão fileinfo não disponível, habilite no php.ini';
   exit;
}
```

Assim você checa se a função existe.

Note que usar `$_FILES['nome']['type']` é pode causar problemas pois em algumas situações atípicas ele pode retornar resultados inesperados, por exemplo você tem um arquivo com a extensão `.jpg`, mas os dados são um `.txt`, quando faz o upload o `[type]` retorna algo como:

```
array(5) {
  ["name"]=>
  string(9) "teste.jpg"
  ["type"]=>
  string(10) "image/jpeg"
  ["tmp_name"]=>
  string(19) "Z:\.tmp\php4EA4.tmp"
  ["error"]=>
  int(0)
  ["size"]=>
  int(3)
}
```

Mas na verdade o `teste.jpg` possui apenas isto no conteudo `a b c`, então quando for usar coisas como `imagecreatefromjpeg` vai ter problemas, eu sei que parece improvavel ter um arquivo que não é imagem mas com a extensão `.jpg`, mas existem muitos casos aonde o arquivo é um `webp` ou `png`, mas o cliente baixou como `jpeg`, então se ele vier a fazer upload isso poderá confundir teu script, também existe a possibilidade do usuário baixar uma foto e ela vir truncada mas ele não se de conta e em seguida vai subir pro seu servidor.

Aplicações feitas em Flash também costuma enviar o type como `application/octet-stream` em requisições como citado pelo em [Comparar extensão de arquivo](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/73490/comparar-extens%C3%A3o-de-arquivo/73497#comment150641_73497):

> ... Eu já vi gente dizendo o contrário, e já vi casos em que o mime-type vem errado ou inútil (application/octet-stream, que pode ser qualquer coisa).

Nem sempre é possivel habiltiar a extensão, mas em alguns servidores é possivel usar uma função chamada `dl();`, mas ainda sim você pode tentar:

```
function carregarExtensao($nome)
{
    if (!extension_loaded($nome)) {
        if (strtoupper(substr(PHP_OS, 0, 3)) === 'WIN') {
            //Carrega em Windows
            return dl('php_' . $nome . '.dll');
        } else {
            //Carrega em unix-like
            return dl($nome . '.so');
        }
    }

    return true;
}

if (!carregarExtensao('fileinfo')) {
     echo 'Não foi possivel carregar a extensão';
     exit;
}
```

> **NOTA:** Esta função foi removida na maioria dos SAPIs no PHP5.3.0 e foi removida no PHP-FPM na versão PHP7

Se não funcionar no seu servidor, então não é possível.

Comment: Entendi Guilherme muita esclarecedora sua explicação, Mas existe a possibilidade de caso esteja desabilitado a extensao,meu código habilitar essa extensão para poder executar o mimetype tranquilamente ?

Comment: @Caleb por isso te perguntei se era verificar ou habilitar rs, então não tem como ativar em tempo de execução infelizmente. Existe até uma função vou editar a resposta e colocar um exemplo.

Comment: Caso extension=php_fileinfo.dll estivesse desabilitado eu queria executar outra comparação de extensão sem ser utilizando mimetype, mas com vc disse o servidor fica muito vulnerável a receber arqruivos indevidos. Melhor só realizar só a verificação mesmo e ativar manualmente. Mas vou testar a função que vc mandou ! Valeu pela disponibilidade de me ajudar !

Comment: @Caleb muitas extensões vem desabilitadas nos servidores pra melhorar a perfomance, então habilitamos apenas o que necessitamos usar. Hoje é tão comum (ou melhor necessário) o uso de fileinfo, realmente seria interessante se já viesse habilitado, quem sabe no php7 =)

Answer (score 1):

## Verificando se a extensão foi carregada

```
if (!extension_loaded('fileinfo')) {
    // a extensão fileinfo não está carregada
} else {
    // a extensão fileinfo foi carregada
}
```

http://php.net/extension_loaded

## A variável global `$_FILES`

Caso queria obter o mime type no momento de um upload, pode buscar a informação diretamente na variável global `$_FILES`.

Exemplo

```
$_FILES['nome_do_campo']['type']
```

Nesse caso não precisa de extensão específica como a [Fileinfo](http://php.net/fileinfo) e é mais seguro do que "apelar" para a extensão da nomenclatura do arquivo.

No entanto, não confie 100% num único parâmetro. A variável $_FILES resgata informações providas pelo cliente (browser por exemplo).

## A função nativa `getimagesize()`

No PHP, existe a função nativa [getimagesize()](http://php.net/getimagesize) onde poderá obter informações sobre o arquivo.

```
$size = getimagesize($filename);
echo $size['mime'] // aqui o mime-type.
```

## Sugestão de implementação

Um exemplo de como pode implementar uma rotina que lê o tipo do arquivo:

```
$path = '/local/do/arquivo.jpg';

if (!extension_loaded('fileinfo')) {
    /*
    Obtendo informação de getimagesize()
    */
    $size = getimagesize($path);
    $mime_type = $size['mime']; // aqui o mime-type.
    unset($size);
} else {
    /*
    Obtendo informação de Fileinfo
    */
    $mime_type = finfo_open(FILEINFO_MIME, $path);
}

'O tipo do arquivo é: '.$mime_type;
```