# Adicionar um valor inicial no array

Tags: php

Gostaria de saber se existe algum modo de adicionar um valor no inicio de cada array , estou criando uma galeria para um site mas estou inserindo as imagens no banco mas preciso renomear cada upload para que não tenha imagens com o mesmo nome .

esse é o codigo

```
if (!is_dir($diretorio)){ echo "Pasta $diretorio nao existe";} 

    else { echo "A Pasta Existe<br>";
            $arquivo = isset($_FILES['arquivo']) ? $_FILES['arquivo'] : FALSE;
            $nome = 'test';
            for ($k = 0; $k < count($arquivo['name']); $k++)
            {
                $destino = $diretorio."/".$nome.$arquivo['name'][$k];
                 $imgs = $arquivo['name'];
                 $array  = implode(',', $imgs);
                    var_dump($array);
                    $inserir->insert('test', ' img=? ',array($array)); 


                if (move_uploaded_file($arquivo['tmp_name'][$k], $destino))
                 { 
                   echo "foi"; 

                 }

                else 
                {
                    echo "não foi";
                }
            }     


        } // fecha else
}
```

na hora que ele faz o upload ele ja vai com o nome correto , mas no banco de dados ele enviar apenas o nome que ja estava não mudando para qual eu escolhi.

Bom eu tentei usando o implode ja usando o valor depois da virgula ',test' mas o índice do array 0 fica sem o valor que foi colocado.

Comment: Mais simples que isso seria não usar o nome original ao salvar. Bastaria salvar com o próprio ID do banco. 000001.jpg, 000002.jpg e assim por diante. Se quiser nomes mais curtos, dá pra usar base64 ou hexa. Se precisar do nome original para algo, apenas guarde no DB.

Comment: então como faço para usar a id para mandar para o banco ? ja tentei usar md5 mas vai apenas para o servidor e não vai para o banco o novo nome

Comment: `$imgs = $nome . $arquivo['name'];`

Comment: Asim serve apenas para mudar para enviar para o servidor , mas preciso inserir no banco .

Comment: Você já está mandando os dados para o banco antes de salvar a imagem, basta usar o ID retornado na inserção como sendo o nome do arquivo. Não precisa gravar o nome novo no banco, afinal, se é o ID que veio do banco ele já está lá.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A pergunta pede "adicionar valor inicial no array" mas o certo seria "concatenar valor nos items do array". São coisas distintas.

Para deixar mais claro

```
$arr = array() // isso aqui é um array



// $arr é um array, mas os valores dentro, não são arrays.
$arr = array(
    'foo', // isso aqui não é um array.. é uma string
    'bar' // idem
)
```

Sem mais delongas, vamos direto ao assunto,

```
        for ($k = 0; $k < count($arquivo['name']); $k++)
        {
            $destino = $diretorio."/".$nome.$arquivo['name'][$k];
             $imgs = $arquivo['name'];
             $array  = implode(',', $imgs);
                var_dump($array);
                $inserir->insert('test', ' img=? ',array($array)); 


            if (move_uploaded_file($arquivo['tmp_name'][$k], $destino))
             { 
               echo "foi"; 

             }

            else 
            {
                echo "não foi";
            }
        }
```

Nesse trecho, opinião pessoal, eu vejo um erro de lógica.

Está gravando no banco de dados antes de concluir o upload.

O que acontece se o `move_uploaded_file()` falhar? Corre o risco de ter dados no banco sem relação com um arquivo existente.

Sugiro que inverta, completando a migração do arquivo e então salvando os dados no banco de dados.

Note o termo "migração" pois é diferente de upload. Nesse ponto o upload já foi feito e o arquivo está no servidor. A função `move_uploaded_file()` apenas moverá o arquivo para um outro local. Mas enfim, não é esse o foco aqui.

```
    for ($k = 0; $k < count($arquivo['name']); $k++) {
        $destino = $diretorio."/".$nome.$arquivo['name'][$k];
        if (move_uploaded_file($arquivo['tmp_name'][$k], $destino)) { 
            echo "foi"; 
            $movido[] = $arquivo['name'][$k];
        } else {
            echo "não foi";
        }
    } 
    if (isset($movido) && !empty($movido)) {
         var_dump($movido);
         $inserir->insert('test', ' img=? ', $movido));
    }
```

Caso queira setar nomes únicos, poderia fazer isso

```
$movido[] = $k.'_'.$arquivo['name'][$k];
```

Mas para isso teria que ter o mesmo padrão aqui também:

```
$destino = $k.'_'.$diretorio."/".$nome.$arquivo['name'][$k];
```

Senão perde a referência e fica sem sentido.

Apenas esteja ciente de que isso não garante nomes únicos.

Num próximo upload com arquivo de mesmo nome, terá nomes duplicados de qualquer forma.

Algo "ideal" no sentido de que não precisaria se preocupar com isso é gerar uma string "única" ou que dificilmente se repetiria.

Normalmente utilizo "data + tempo" no formato timestamp.

Facaria assim:

```
$str = $arquivo['name'][$k];
$extensao = substr($str, strrpos($str, '.')+1); // não confie muito nisso.*

$arquivo_nome = time().'_'.$k.'.'.$extensao;

$movido[] = $arquivo_nome;

$destino = $k.'_'.$diretorio.'/'.$arquivo_nome;

/*
Os nomes dos arquivos será algo como:
2367639897_1.jpg
2367639897_2.jpg
2367639897_3.jpg
*/

 /*
 O motivo de incrementar os números sequenciais ao timestamp é que a execução é tão rápida que o timestamp se repetirá. Por isso, os números sequenciais concatenados dão uma unicidade. 

 Esteja ciente que isso também não garante 100%. Num sistema com múltiplos acessos, pode acontecer de 2 ou mais usuários simultaneamente executando o upload e coincidentemente obter o mesmo timestamp.

 Caso queira garantir ainda mais a unicidade, poderia concatenar com o ID do usuário logado, o ID de sessão, ou qualquer coisa que seja único daquele usuário mesmo que não esteja logado. Nesse caso só teria duplicidade se uma mesma conta estivesse logada em locais diferentes por pessoas diferentes e executando tudo ao mesmo tempo. A probabilidade é muito remota, porém, possível de acontecer. Enfim, você tem que ir pensando nas diversas possibilidades considerando até onde é viável dentro do contexto do modelo de negócios. Nem sempre precisará elaborar com tanta minuciosidade.
```

Opcionalmente, caso já possua um ID único relacionado com essas imagens, poderá usar esse ID no lugar do timestamp ou qualquer outra coisa que preferir. O sistema é seu, faça como quiser.
*/

Importante: Esteja ciente que sou alheio ao que é executado no método `$inserir::insert()`. Portanto, não posso prever erros posteriores que possam ocorrer.

obs:

Nesse trecho do exemplo:

```
$extensao = substr($str, strrpos($str, '.')+1); // não confie muito nisso.*
```

O ideal é determinar a extensão de acordo com a informação do mime-type.

Um usuário pode enviar um `arquivo.gif` mesmo sendo um `image/jpg`. Ou seja, o nome é **.gif** mas a imagem é um **jpg**.

Os browsers normalmente exibem, mas há browsers que bloqueiam. Por isso, tenha precaução sobre a forma como obtém ou determina a extensão do arquivo.

Consulte: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/119493/4793

Comment: Obrigado man deu certo consegui mandar pro banco como uma string com o nome gerado na $nome , muito obrigado :) , sei que tem outro modo mas eu queria inserir uma string com todas as imagens apenas separando por "," e deu certo :) mt obg.