# Como proteger upload de arquivos em php contra shell script

Tags: php, file-upload, shell, shell-script

Como posso proteger o envio de arquivos com php contra shell script, sabendo que aceito apenas um tipo de extensão.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ao invés de checar a extensão você pode checar o conteudo usando a API do PHP chamada [**fileinfo**](http://php.net/manual/en/book.fileinfo.php), como mostrei nesta resposta https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/73497/3635

> Note que no PHP5.3 (apesar de raro alguns servidores ainda o usam) não tinhamos `Fileinfo`, mas tínhamos `mime_content_type` (na documentação não fala se esta em desuso), então eu coloquei como fallback, se uma função estiver disponível usa ela, se não tenta a mais antiga, todavia ambas sempre veem habilitadas.

Exemplo:

```
<?php

function mimeType($file)
{
    $mimetype = false;

    if (class_exists('finfo')) {//PHP5.4+
        $finfo     = finfo_open(FILEINFO_MIME_TYPE);
        $mimetype  = finfo_file($finfo, $file);
        finfo_close($finfo);
    } else if (function_exists('mime_content_type')) {//php5.3 ou inferiror
        $mimetype = mime_content_type($file);
    }

    return $mimetype;
}

//Libere aqui os tipos permitidos
$validos = array( 'image/jpeg', 'image/png', 'image/gif', 'text/plain' );

$location = 'uploads/';
$arquivo = $_FILES['file'];

if ($arquivo) {
    $name = $arquivo['name'];
    $tmp_name = $arquivo['tmp_name'];

    if ($_FILES['file']['error'] !== UPLOAD_ERR_OK) {
        echo 'Erro ao fazer o upload:', $error;
    } else {
        //Pega o mimetype
        $mimeType = mimeType($tmp_name);

        //Checa o mimetype com o array
        if (!in_array($mimeType, $validos)) {
            echo 'Formato de arquivo invalid';
        } elseif (move_uploaded_file($tmp_name, $location . $name)) {
            echo 'Upload completo';
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: muito obrigado amigo :)

Comment: ok irei testar agora de manha

Comment: acredito que não está pegando o mime corretamente, sempre cai na funcao dizendo que é invalido, mesmo sendo um arquivo permitido

Comment: ué retornou: bool(false)

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/47572/discussion-between-jefferson-mello-olynyki-and-guilherme-nascimento).

Comment: acredito que nao tenha o mime type na versao 5.2 do php

Comment: estou mudando os script para versoes mais recentes, é muito antigo tem muitas funcoes depreciadas, estou atualizando, ai irei utilizar fileinfo mesmo

Comment: sim sao funcoes antigas mesmo, eregi ereg, variaveis exibidas como undefined, mas já estou ajustando, é melhor até do que ficar limitado, os scripts foram criados em 2006 :)

Comment: http://pastebin.com/k6xdEswX

Comment: @JeffersonMelloOlynyki faz um tempo que não uso php5.2, mas tenta tirar o `;` desta linha `;extension=php_mime_magic.dll` deixando assim `extension=php_mime_magic.dll` e reinicia o Apache/Wamp/Xampp e veja se funciona