# Montar playlist com ítens da pasta/diretório e reproduzir a playlist em loop

Tags: php, html

Basicamente eu gostava de ter um vídeo player na minha página do `index.html` que passasse todos os vídeos que eu tenho numa pasta, ou seja, se eu eliminar ou mover outro vídeo para essa pasta, o vídeo player passa todos os que lá estão, seja qual for o título do vídeo.

Também queria que ao fim do último vídeo que passou da pasta, voltasse a passar tudo de novo.

Comment: Refiz os scripts pode testar o 3 e o 4, o 1 era só pra explicar e o 2 é para usar com mp3

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Basicamente para criar uma playlist com a tag video será necessário usar javascript, usando um array e o evento `onended` na tag `<video>`:

```
<video id="player-video" controls></video>

<script type="text/javascript">
(function () {
    var playerVideo = document.getElementById("player-video");
    var current = 0;
    var videos = [];

    videos.push("videos/1.mp4");
    videos.push("videos/2.mp4");
    videos.push("videos/3.webm");

    function nextVideo() {
        playerVideo.src = videos[current];

        current++;

        playerVideo.play();

        if (current >= videos.length) {
            current = 0;
        }
    }

    playerVideo.addEventListener("ended", nextVideo);

    nextVideo();

})();
</script>
```

Note que isto também funciona com a tag `<audio>`:

```
<audio id="player-audio" controls></audio>

<script type="text/javascript">
(function () {
    var playerAudio = document.getElementById("player-audio");
    var current = 0;
    var audios = [];

    audios.push("videos/1.mp3");
    audios.push("videos/2.mp3");
    audios.push("videos/3.ogg");

    function nextVideo() {
        playerAudio.src = audios[current];

        current++;

        playerAudio.play();

        if (current >= audios.length) {
            current = 0;
        }
    }

    playerAudio.addEventListener("ended", nextAudio);

    nextAudio();

})();
</script>
```

Sendo PHP pode usar `opendir` e na tag audio basta usar o atributo `loop`

Fiz este exemplo supondo que sejam todos videos do tipo mp4 (provavelmente codec h264)

```
<?php
$dir = './'; //Troque pela sua pasta relativa

if (is_dir($dir) && $dh = opendir($dir)) {
?>

    <video id="player-video" controls></video>

    <script type="text/javascript">
    (function () {
        var playerVideo = document.getElementById("player-video");
        var current = 0;
        var videos = [];

        <?php while (($file = readdir($dh)) !== false): ?>
        <?php if (is_file($dir . '/' . $file)): ?>

        videos.push("<?php echo rtrim($dir, '/'), '/', $file; ?>");

        <?php endif; ?>
        <?php endwhile; ?>

        function nextVideo() {
            playerVideo.src = videos[current];

            current++;

            playerVideo.play();

            if (current >= videos.length) {
                current = 0;
            }
        }

        playerVideo.addEventListener("ended", nextVideo);

        nextVideo();

    })();
    </script>

<?php
     closedir($dh);
}
?>
```

Todavia você pode usar a função que postei aqui https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/73497/3635 para detectar melhor os mimetypes, ficaria assim:

```
<?php
function mimeType($file)
{
    $mimetype = false;

    if (class_exists('finfo')) {//PHP5.4+
        $finfo     = finfo_open(FILEINFO_MIME_TYPE);
        $mimetype  = finfo_file($finfo, $file);
        finfo_close($finfo);
    } else if (function_exists('mime_content_type')) {//php5.3 ou inferiror
        $mimetype = mime_content_type($file);
    }

    return $mimetype;
}

$dir = './'; //Troque pela sua pasta relativa

if (is_dir($dir) && $dh = opendir($dir)) {
?>

    <video id="player-video" controls></video>

    <script type="text/javascript">
    (function () {
        var playerVideo = document.getElementById("player-video");
        var current = 0;
        var videos = [];

        <?php while (($file = readdir($dh)) !== false): ?>
        <?php if (is_file($dir . '/' . $file)): ?>

        <?php $mimetype = mimeType($dir . '/' . $file); ?>

        <?php if (strpos($mimetype, 'video/') === 0): ?>

            videos.push({
                "path": "<?php echo rtrim($dir, '/'), '/', $file; ?>",
                "type": "<?php echo $mimetype; ?>"
            });

        <?php endif; ?>
        <?php endif; ?>
        <?php endwhile; ?>

        function nextVideo() {
            playerVideo.type = videos[current].type;
            playerVideo.src = videos[current].path;

            console.log(current);

            current++;

            playerVideo.play();

            if (current >= videos.length) {
                current = 0;
            }
        }

        playerVideo.addEventListener("ended", nextVideo);

        nextVideo();

    })();
    </script>

<?php
     closedir($dh);
}
?>
```