# Criar fluxo de controle na playlist para web player

Tags: javascript, html

Para exemplificar o que estou querendo, observe a figura:

## Screen Shot

[image]

Para isso coloco o código fonte para exemplo:

## Código

```
<html>

<head>

<style type="text/css">
#slide #screenshot {
width: 480px;
height: 360px;
border: solid 3px #333;
}

#slide a {
border: solid 1px #333;
background-color: #F7F7F7;
padding: 5px;
text-decoration: none;
color: #000;
}

#slide a:hover {
border: solid 1px #333;
text-decoration: underline;
background-color: #333;
color: #FFF;
}

#slide a.hover {
background-color: #333;
color: #FFF;
}

#slide #controle {
width: 480px;
height: 360px;
text-align: center;
padding-top: 15px;
}
</style>

</head>

<body>

<div id="slide">

<div id="screenshot">

<img src="screenshot/1.jpg" width="480px" height="360px" border="0" alt="Banner">

</div>

<div id="controle">

<a href="#" onclick="troca(1);"> &#171 Anterior </a>&nbsp;&nbsp;

<a href="javascript:void(0);" id="screenshot1" class="hover" onclick="troca('0');">1</a>
<a href="javascript:void(0);" id="screenshot2" onclick="troca('1');">2</a>
<a href="javascript:void(0);" id="screenshot3" onclick="troca('2');">3</a>
<a href="javascript:void(0);" id="screenshot4" onclick="troca('3');">4</a>

&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href="#" onclick="troca(-1);"> Próximo &#187 </a>

</div>

</div>

</body>

<script>
img = ['1', '2', '3', '4']

indice = 0;

function troca(i) {

    if (i == 0 || i == 1 || i == 2 || i == 3) {

        indice = i;

    } else {

        if (indice == img.length - 1) {

            indice = 0;

        } else {

            indice++;

        }

    }
    document.getElementById("screenshot1").setAttribute("class", "");
    document.getElementById("screenshot2").setAttribute("class", "");
    document.getElementById("screenshot3").setAttribute("class", "");
    document.getElementById("screenshot4").setAttribute("class", "");
    document.getElementById("screenshot" + img[indice]).setAttribute("class", "hover");

    document.getElementById("screenshot").innerHTML = "<img src='screenshot/" + img[indice] + ".jpg' width='480' height='360' border='0' alt='snap shot'>";
}
</script>

<html>
```

Não defini **thumbnail** nos seguintes links:

```
<a href="javascript:void(0);" id="screenshot1" class="hover" onclick="troca('0');">1</a>
<a href="javascript:void(0);" id="screenshot2" onclick="troca('1');">2</a>
<a href="javascript:void(0);" id="screenshot3" onclick="troca('2');">3</a>
<a href="javascript:void(0);" id="screenshot4" onclick="troca('3');">4</a>
```

Preferi deixar por números para detectar eventuais **erros**, ja que esta em fase de criação.

***A minha dificuldade está em fazer a lógica fluxo controle entre "próximo/anterior"***

> Sei que o problema esta por aqui..

```
if (indice == img.length - 1) {

indice = 0;

} else {

indice++;

}
```

Comment: Veja se isso ajuda http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/168525/3635 (obs: não fui eu quem negativou e também não entendi o motivo)

Comment: Não entendi, é video ou foto?

Comment: Isso esta claro, mas as pessoas (provavelmente) estão esperando tentar entender se você quer passar um video, foto ou outra coisa para criar um exemplo em cima do uso que necessita.

Comment: Veja se a resposta lhe ajuda

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Acredito que o código deva ficar assim:

```js
var img = ['1','2','3','4'];

var indice = 0;

function troca(i) {
    //Verifica se o numero esta dentro da quantidade de indices
    if (i < img.length) {
       indice = i;
    } else {
       return;
    }

    document.getElementById("screenshot1").className = "";
    document.getElementById("screenshot2").className = "";
    document.getElementById("screenshot3").className = "";
    document.getElementById("screenshot4").className = "";
    document.getElementById("screenshot" + img[indice]).className = "hover";

    document.getElementById("screenshot").innerHTML = "<img src='screenshot/" + img[indice] + ".jpg' width='480' height='360' border='0' alt='screenshot/" + img[indice] + ".jpg'>";
}

function proximo() {
    //Soma mais 1 e se passar do limite do indice torna 0 novamente
    indice++;

    if (indice >= img.length) {
       indice = 0;
    }

    troca(indice);
}

function anterior() {
    //Subtrai 1, se for menor que 0 move para o ultimo item do indice
    indice--;

    if (indice < 0) {
       indice = img.length - 1;
    }

    troca(indice);
}
```

```css
.hover {
    padding: 5px;
    background-color: #F00;
    color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<div id="screenshot">

<img src="screenshot/1.jpg" width="480px" height="360px" border="0" alt="1">

</div>

<a href="#" onclick="anterior();"> &#171 Anterior </a>&nbsp;&nbsp;

<a href="javascript:void(0);" id="screenshot1" class="hover" onclick="troca('0');">1</a>
<a href="javascript:void(0);" id="screenshot2" onclick="troca('1');">2</a>
<a href="javascript:void(0);" id="screenshot3" onclick="troca('2');">3</a>
<a href="javascript:void(0);" id="screenshot4" onclick="troca('3');">4</a>

&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href="#" onclick="proximo();">Próximo &#187</a>
```

Comment: Agradeço, desde ja pelo tempo disposto em me ajudar. Coloco o meu voto sobre seu desempenho por finalizar com precisão e atenção.

Answer (score 2):

Altera a sua função `troca` por essa aqui que deve funcionar. Tente adicionar um JSFiddle que vai ajudar muito.

```js
img = ['1','2','3','4']

indice = 0;

function resetThumbnail () {
 document.getElementById("screenshot1").className = "";
    document.getElementById("screenshot2").className = "";
    document.getElementById("screenshot3").className = "";
    document.getElementById("screenshot4").className = "";
    document.getElementById("screenshot" + img[indice]).className = "hover";
}

function troca(i) {
    indice += i;

    resetThumbnail();

    this.className = 'hover';

    // edit - adicionando um limitador.
    if (indice < 0) {
        indice = 0;
    } else if (indice > img.length - 1) {
        indice = img.length - 1;
    }

    document.getElementById("screenshot").innerHTML = "<img src='screenshot/" + img[indice] + ".jpg' width='480' height='360' border='0' alt='snap shot'>";
}
```

```css
#slide #screenshot {
width: 480px;
height: 360px;
border: solid 3px #333;
}

#slide a {
border: solid 1px #333;
background-color: #F7F7F7;
padding: 5px;
text-decoration: none;
color: #000;
}

#slide a:hover {
border: solid 1px #333;
text-decoration: underline;
background-color: #333;
color: #FFF;
}

#slide a.hover {
background-color: #333;
color: #FFF;
}

#slide #controle {
width: 480px;
height: 360px;
text-align: center;
padding-top: 15px;
}
```

```html
<div id="slide">

<div id="screenshot">

<img src="screenshot/1.jpg" width="480px" height="360px" border="0">
    
</div>

<div id="controle">

<a href="#" onclick="troca(-1);"> &#171 Anterior </a>&nbsp;&nbsp;

<a href="javascript:void(0);" id="screenshot1" class="hover" onclick="troca('0');">1</a>
<a href="javascript:void(0);" id="screenshot2" onclick="troca('1');">2</a>
<a href="javascript:void(0);" id="screenshot3" onclick="troca('2');">3</a>
<a href="javascript:void(0);" id="screenshot4" onclick="troca('3');">4</a>

&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href="#" onclick="troca(1);"> Próximo &#187 </a>

</div>

</div>
```

Eu não entendi o propósito do restante da sua função.

Comment: `troca(-1);` vai alterar a `<img>` para o índice anterior, `troca(1);` para a próxima.

Comment: No seu código a thumbnail tbm não está funcionando?

Comment: Atualizei o código, teste aí.

Comment: Fico contente por ter partilhado comigo um pouco do seu conhecimento, embora não sei o porque ainda, não funcionou como deveria. Mas ficou claro como aprendizado.

Comment: Ja descobri o caso do teu código falhar em meus testes. Vou reeditar sua reposta com detalhe exato. Assim ficará para futura pesquisa como a segunda alternativa a esta questão.