# Tag <audio> — Fade e reprodução individual

Tags: áudio, html5-audio

Tenho uma página com vários áudios, usando o player nativo html5. Preciso adicionar fade in/out nos áudios e de alguma forma permitir que apenas um áudio seja reproduzido por vez. Alguma luz? rs

```html
<audio class="borda-player" src="audios/9.mp3" controls></audio>
```

Comment: Você está usando jQuery no seu projeto?

Comment: Olha esse artigo https://dailygit.com/fade-in-and-fade-out-audio-with-html5-api/

Comment: O fade se refere ao som indo diminuindo? Creio que isto já seja um começo https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/168525/3635

Comment: @ThallesOliveira Conseguiu resolver?

Answer (score 0):

Sei que é uma pergunta antiga, mas eu vou deixar um exemplo de interação brincando com o controle de volume.

```js
$('document').ready(function() {
  var player = document.getElementById("player");
  var auxVolume = document.getElementById("player").volume;
  var lastVolume = 0;
  var currentTrack = -1;
  var onFade = false;
  var playlist = [
      {
      titulo: 'Onda',
      url: 'http://www.sample-videos.com/audio/mp3/wave.mp3',
      duracao: '00:00:45'
    },
    {
      titulo: 'Aplausos',
      url: 'http://www.sample-videos.com/audio/mp3/crowd-cheering.mp3',
      duracao: '00:00:27'
    }

  ];

  var fadeOnStart = function() {
    if (player.currentTime == 0) {
      var originalVolume = auxVolume;
      player.volume = 0;
      $(player).animate({
        volume: auxVolume
      }, 2000);
    }
  };

  var fadeOut = function() {
    if (!onFade) {
      var originalVolume = auxVolume;
      onFade = true;
      $(player).animate({
        volume: 0
      }, 2000, function() {
        onFade = false;
        lastVolume = originalVolume;
        playNext();
        

      });
    }
  }

  var playNext = function() {
    if((currentTrack < playlist.length -1)){
      currentTrack++
    }else{
      currentTrack = 0;
    }
    
      player.setAttribute('src', playlist[currentTrack].url);
      player.load();
      player.volume = lastVolume;
      player.play();
  }

  var monitor = function() {
    if (player.currentTime >= (player.duration - 2)) {
      fadeOut();
    }
  }

  var start = function() {
    lastVolume = 0.35;
    playNext();
    
    player.onplay = function() {
      fadeOnStart()
    };
    player.ontimeupdate = function() {
      monitor()
    }
    player.onvolumechange = function() {
      auxVolume = player.volume;
    }
  }();
});
```

```css
audio {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<audio id="player" controls></audio>
```

> Esse exemplo foi só um beta, em um segundo momento irei editar o código para deixá-lo mais enxuto e parametrizável. Mas pode ser um ponto de partida para atingir o que você procura, se o seu objetivo é ter vários players e ao selecionar um novo faça o fadeout do que estiver tocando e depois comece o novo, deixe um comentário que eu edito a resposta.