# Como realizar upload de arquivos seguro?

Tags: php, upload, file-upload

Quero realizar o *upload* de arquivos de forma segura sem me preocupar com a extensão. Tenho medo de alguém tentar enviar um arquivo para o meu site e executar ele dentro do servidor, não sei se e possível mais me bateu o medo.

- Como posso verificar se o arquivo é mesmo uma imagem?
- Posso bloquear para só selecionar arquivos do tipo `.jpg` `.png` `.gif` na janela que se abre para selecionar o arquivo?

Comment: Não consegui entender como fazer para realizar a verificação nessa pergunta por isso realizei a minha.

Answer (score 0):

Para verificar se o arquivo é mesmo uma imagem, através de PHP, já existe uma pergunta respondida sobre isso em [Qual é a forma mais segura para se identificar que o arquivo de upload é uma imagem?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/178737/66203).

---

Agora, respondendo como bloquear alguns tipos de arquivos na caixa de seleção que aparece, sua "*melhor*" opção é utilizar o atributo [accept](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/file) da *tag* de entrada. No código abaixo você permite arquivos do tipo `.jpg`, `.png`, e `.gif`. Veja no *snippet*:

```html
<input type="file"  accept="image/x-png, image/gif, image/jpeg" />
```

Ou se quiser permitir todos tipos de imagem pode fazer da seguinte maneira:

```html
<input type="file" accept="image/*" />
```

Importante ressaltar que isso apenas sugere para o navegador quais tipos de arquivos **exibir** para o usuário, entretanto isso pode ser facilmente contornado, então é de **extrema importância** você fazer a validação do arquivo carregado no **servidor também**. Embora normalmente possa ser contornado pelos usuários, ele ajuda a reduzir os resultados para os usuários por padrão, para que eles possam obter exatamente o que eles estão procurando, sem ter que passar por uma centena de tipos de arquivos diferentes.

Para obter mais informações detalhadas sobre o suporte aos navegadores, você pode olhar no [Can I Use](http://caniuse.com/#feat=input-file-accept). Mas, rapidamente, o `accept` tem suporte no IE 11, no Firefox desde a versão 56, e no Chrome desde a versão 49. Já nos dispositivos móveis, o suporte é bem incompleto. Alguns como o Edge e Opera Mini não possuem suporte.

---

Também temos uma pergunta respondida sobre isso no nosso [Grande Irmão SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6225815).