# Dificuldade para utilizar o ob_start(); o ob_end_flush(); e seus similares?

Tags: php, javascript

Segue as linhas da programação. Inclusive eu já li um material que foi dispo nibilizado aqui no stackoverflow mas ainda não consegui resolver meu problema. **Sou programador amador** e devido a este Warning não consigo acessar uma outra parte do Painel que diz respeito ao Passo2 para Cadastro de Produtos pois ocorre este seguinte aviso:

*Strict Standards: Only variables should be passed by reference in /home/chanc184/public_html/classes/Site.class.php on line 214
Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /home/chanc184/public_html/admin/painel/inc/header.php:39) in /home/chanc184/public_html/admin/painel/pages/cadProdutos.php on line 55*

**DESDE JÁ AGRADEÇO A QUEM PODER ME AJUDAR. OBRIGADO**

```
<?php
    ob_start();
    session_start();
    include_once "../../config.php";
    function __autoload($classe){
        require_once "../../classes/".$classe.'.class.php';
    }
    BD::conn();
    $login = new Login('adm_', 'loja_adm');
    $site = new Site;
    $val = new Validacao;

    if(!$login->isLogado()){
        header("Location: ../");
        exit;
    }else{
        $pegar_dados = BD::conn()->prepare("SELECT * FROM `loja_adm` WHERE email_log = ? AND senha_log = ?");
        $pegar_dados->execute(array($_SESSION['adm_emailLog'], $_SESSION['adm_senhaLog']));
        $usuarioLogado = $pegar_dados->fetchObject();
    }
    if(isset($_GET['acao']) && $_GET['acao'] == 'sair'):
        if($login->deslogar()){
            header("Location: ../");
        }
    endif;
    ob_end_flush();
?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Chances de Ouro - Painel de Administração</title>
<link href="css/style_painel.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/tiny_mce/tiny_mce.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../../js/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/botoes.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../../js/price.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/functions.js"></script>
<?php if(!isset($_GET['pagina'])):?>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      google.load("visualization", "1", {packages:["corechart"]});
      google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
      function drawChart() {
        var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
          ['Task', 'Hours per Day'],
         <?php
            $sqlVendas = BD::conn()->prepare("SELECT *, SUM(valor_total) AS total_venda FROM `loja_pedidos` 
                                                WHERE TO_DAYS(NOW()) - TO_DAYS(criado) <= 90 GROUP BY MONTH(criado)");
            $sqlVendas->execute();
            while($fetchVendas = $sqlVendas->fetchObject()){
         ?>
          ['<?php echo date('m/Y', strtotime($fetchVendas->criado));?>', <?php echo $fetchVendas->total_venda;?>],
         <?php }?>
        ]);

        var options = {
          title: 'Ganho trimestral de vendas em R$',
          'width':610,
          'height':240
        };

        var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('grafico'));
        chart.draw(data, options);
      }
    </script>
<?php endif;?> 
</head>

<body>

<div id="box">
    <div id="header">
        <div class="logo">  </div>
    </div><!-- header -->
<div id="content_painel">
```

Primeiro obrigado por responderem prontamente e segundo desculpe por não ter sido muito especifico, pensei que tivesse ido a linha na qual consta o problema, bem pelas pesquisas que fiz no google o output ocorre nesta linha que inicia o Warning:

> **...(output started at /home/chanc184/public_html/admin/painel/inc/header.php:39)**

A linha 39 no meu script corresponde a esse código em PHP

```
<?php if(!isset($_GET['pagina'])):?>`

    <?php
        ob_start();
        session_start();
        include_once "../../config.php";
        function __autoload($classe){
            require_once "../../classes/".$classe.'.class.php';
        }
        BD::conn();
        $login = new Login('adm_', 'loja_adm');
        $site = new Site;
        $val = new Validacao;

        if(!$login->isLogado()){
            header("Location: ../");
            exit;
        }else{
            $pegar_dados = BD::conn()->prepare("SELECT * FROM `loja_adm` WHERE email_log = ? AND senha_log = ?");
            $pegar_dados->execute(array($_SESSION['adm_emailLog'], $_SESSION['adm_senhaLog']));
            $usuarioLogado = $pegar_dados->fetchObject();
        }
        if(isset($_GET['acao']) && $_GET['acao'] == 'sair'):
            if($login->deslogar()){
                header("Location: ../");
            }
        endif;
        ob_end_flush();
    ?>
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <title> Painel de Administração</title>
    <link href="css/style_painel.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/tiny_mce/tiny_mce.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../../js/jquery.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/botoes.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../../js/price.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/functions.js"></script>
    ***<?php if(!isset($_GET['pagina'])):?>Linha 39***
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
          google.load("visualization", "1", {packages:["corechart"]});
          google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
          function drawChart() {
            var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
              ['Task', 'Hours per Day'],
             <?php
                $sqlVendas = BD::conn()->prepare("SELECT *, SUM(valor_total) AS total_venda FROM `loja_pedidos` 
                                                    WHERE TO_DAYS(NOW()) - TO_DAYS(criado) <= 90 GROUP BY MONTH(criado)");
                $sqlVendas->execute();
                while($fetchVendas = $sqlVendas->fetchObject()){
             ?>
              ['<?php echo date('m/Y', strtotime($fetchVendas->criado));?>', <?php echo $fetchVendas->total_venda;?>],
             <?php }?>
            ]);

            var options = {
              title: 'Ganho trimestral de vendas em R$',
              'width':610,
              'height':240
            };

            var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('grafico'));
            chart.draw(data, options);
          }
        </script>
    <?php endif;?> 
    </head>

    <body>

    <div id="box">
        <div id="header">
            <div class="logo">  </div>
        </div><!-- header -->
    <div id="content_painel">
```

Em minhas pesquisas li que o output pode ocorrer quando há código `PHP` após HTML. Estou aprendendo mais sobre as aplicações do `ob_start()` e seus similares mas ainda não consegui solucionar meu problema. 
Esse script este dentro da pasta `Inc` na estrutura do meu site e faz a chamada para que possa utilizar a página `cadprodutos.php`, que trata da segunda parte do

> **Warning:in /home/chanc184/public_html/admin/painel/pages/cadProdutos.php **on
>   line 55** **

segue o script abaixo:

```
h1 class="title">Cadastrar novo Produto</h1>
<?php
if(isset($_POST['acao']) && $_POST['acao'] == 'cadastrar'):
include_once "inc/slug.php";
    $img_padrao = $_FILES['img_padrao'];
    $titulo = strip_tags(filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'titulo'));
    $slug = slug($titulo);
    $categoria = $_POST['categoria'];
    $subcategoria = $_POST['subcategoria'];

    $val_anterior = $_POST['valAnterior'];
    $val_atual = $_POST['valAtual'];
    $descricao = htmlentities($_POST['descricao'], ENT_QUOTES);
    $peso = strip_tags(filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'peso'));
    $qtdEstoque = strip_tags(filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'qtdEstoque'));

    $verificar_slug = BD::conn()->prepare("SELECT id FROM `loja_produtos` WHERE slug = ?");
    $verificar_slug->execute(array($slug));
    if($verificar_slug->rowCount() > 0){
        $slug .= $verificar_slug->rowCount();
    }

    $val->set($titulo, 'Titulo')->obrigatorio();
    $val->set($categoria, 'Categoria')->obrigatorio();
    $val->set($subcategoria, 'Subcategoria')->obrigatorio();
    $val->set($val_atual, 'Valor Atual')->obrigatorio();
    $val->set($descricao, 'Descrição')->obrigatorio();
    $val->set($peso, 'Peso')->obrigatorio();
    $val->set($qtdEstoque, 'Quantidade em Estoque')->obrigatorio();

    if(!$val->validar()){
        $erro = $val->getErro();
        echo '<div class="erros">Erro: '.$erro[0].'</div>';
    }elseif($img_padrao['error'] == '4'){
        echo '<div class="erros">Informe uma imagem padrão para o produto!</div>';
    }else{
    $nomeImg = md5(uniqid(rand(), true)).$img_padrao['name'];
    $site->upload($img_padrao['tmp_name'], $img_padrao['name'], $nomeImg, '350', '../../produtos/');
    $now = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');

    $dados = array('img_padrao' => $nomeImg, 
                    'titulo' => $titulo, 
                    'slug' => $slug, 
                    'categoria' => $categoria, 
                    'subcategoria' => $subcategoria, 
                    'valor_anterior' => $val_anterior, 
                    'valor_atual' => $val_atual, 
                    'descricao' => $descricao, 
                    'peso' => $peso, 
                    'estoque' => $qtdEstoque, 
                    'qtdVendidos' => 0, 
                    'data' => $now);
        if($site->inserir('loja_produtos', $dados)){
            $_SESSION['ultimoId'] = BD::conn()->lastInsertId();
            **header("Location: index.php?pagina=passo2"); linha 55 - aqui o usuário é redirecionado para a 2 etapa do processo de cadastro de Produto**
        }
    }
endif;
?>
<div id="formularios">
    <form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <label class="img">
            <span class="title">Imagem Padrão</span>
            <input type="file" name="img_padrao" />
        </label>

        <label>
            <span class="title">Titulo do produto</span>
            <input type="text" name="titulo" />
        </label>

        <div class="fix">
            <label>
                <span class="title">Escolha a categoria:</span>
                <select name="categoria">
                    <option value="" selected="selected">Selecione...</option>
                    <?php
                        $pegar_categorias = BD::conn()->prepare("SELECT * FROM `loja_categorias` ORDER BY id DESC");
                        $pegar_categorias->execute();
                        while($cat = $pegar_categorias->fetchObject()){
                    ?>
                    <option value="<?php echo $cat->slug;?>"><?php echo $cat->titulo;?></option>
                    <?php }?>
                </select>
            </label>

            <label>
                <span class="title">Escolha a subcategoria:</span>
                <select name="subcategoria">
                    <option value="" selected="selected">Selecione...</option>
                </select>
            </label>
        </div><!--- div para fixar -->

        <div class="fix">
        <label>
            <span class="title">Valor Anterior</span>
            <input type="text" name="valAnterior" id="preco"/>
        </label>
        <label>
            <span class="title">Valor Atual</span>
            <input type="text" name="valAtual" id="preco1"/>
        </label>
        </div><!--- div para fixar -->

        <label>
            <span class="title">Escreva as características deste produto</span>
            <textarea name="descricao" cols="30" rows="5" id="tiny"></textarea>
        </label>

        <div class="fix">
        <label>
            <span class="title">Peso do produto</span>
            <input type="text" name="peso"/>
        </label>
        <label>
            <span class="title">Quantidade em estoque</span>
            <input type="text" name="qtdEstoque" />
        </label>
        </div><!--- div para fixar -->

        <input type="hidden" name="acao" value="cadastrar" />
        <input type="submit" value="Próximo Passo" class="btn"/>
    </form>
</div>
```

Então é isso....até consigo cadastrar um Produto mas não consigo ser redirecionado para o Passo2 do processo.

Script do Site.class.php.....linha 214

```
function upload($tmp, $name, $nome, $larguraP, $pasta){

    **$ext = end(explode('.', $name));*****LINHA 214***
    if($ext=='jpg' || $ext == 'JPG' || $ext == 'jpeg' || $ext == 'JPEG'){
            $img = imagecreatefromjpeg($tmp);
    }elseif($ext == 'png'){
            $img = imagecreatefrompng($tmp);
    }elseif($ext == 'gif'){
            $img = imagecreatefromgif($tmp);
    }
    list($larg, $alt) = getimagesize($tmp);
    $x = $larg;
    $y = $alt;
    $largura = ($x>$larguraP) ? $larguraP : $x;
    $altura = ($largura*$y)/$x;

    if($altura>$larguraP){
            $altura = $larguraP;
            $largura = ($altura*$x)/$y;
    }
    $nova = imagecreatetruecolor($largura, $altura);
    imagecopyresampled($nova, $img, 0,0,0,0, $largura, $altura, $x, $y);

    imagejpeg($nova, $pasta.$nome);
    imagedestroy($img);
    imagedestroy($nova);
    return (file_exists($pasta.$nome)) ? true : false;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Não está claro onde é o problema.

Aparentemente um único erro desencadeou os seguintes.

```
Strict Standards: Only variables should be passed by reference
```

O erro aponta para `classes/Site.class.php` na  214

Poste o conteúdo desse arquivo na pergunta.

## Sugestões para resolver

Pode resolver da forma correta que é **não** passar por referência.

Também pode optar por algo rápido, desabilitando o "warning". Isso não é recomendável. Faça se realmente for inevitável pois o certo é corrigir os erros:

```
ini_set('display_errors', '0');
error_reporting(E_ALL ^ E_STRICT);
```

Coloque no início do script em execução.

Isso faz com que os avisos do tipo "strict" sejam ocultados.

Se está com pressa em resolver o problema, ocultar o aviso pode resolver o problema e os outros subsequentes.

Claro que não posso garantir que funcionará pois pode existir invocações em outras partes do sistema que modifiquem essas setagens. Esteja ciente, por favor.

## Output buffering?

Quanto as funções de "output buffering", pelo código que postou não é possível dizer se está sendo bem aplicado ou não e tampouco se isso é a raíz do problema. Parece que o sistema depende disso mas não parece ter correlação com o contexto do problema apresentado.

Answer (score 2):

A função [`end()`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.end.php) em:

```
$ext = end(explode('.', $name));
```

Só aceita referencias, veja o que é e como funciona as referencias aqui: http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/language.references.pass.php

Para corrigir basta fazer assim:

```
$dados = explode('.', $name);
$ext = end($dados);
```

Ou assim:

```
$ext = explode('.', $name);
$ext = $ext[count($ext) - 1];
```

No entanto este tipo de verificação do tipo de arquivo baseado na extensão **"não é seguro"**, o melhor seria checar o mimetype que é um pouco mais seguro:

- https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/73497/3635

Poderia ficar assim:

```
function mimeType($file)
{
    $mimetype = false;

    if (class_exists('finfo')) {//PHP5.4+
        $finfo     = finfo_open(FILEINFO_MIME_TYPE);
        $mimetype  = finfo_file($finfo, $file);
        finfo_close($finfo);
    } else if (function_exists('mime_content_type')) {//php5.3 ou inferiror
        $mimetype = mime_content_type($file);
    }

    return $mimetype;
}

function upload($tmp, $name, $nome, $larguraP, $pasta){
    $type = mimeType($tmp);

    if($type == 'image/jpeg'){
            $img = imagecreatefromjpeg($tmp);
    }elseif($type == 'image/png'){
            $img = imagecreatefrompng($tmp);
    }elseif($type == 'image/gif'){
            $img = imagecreatefromgif($tmp);
    } else {
       return false;
    }

    list($larg, $alt) = getimagesize($tmp);
    $x = $larg;
    $y = $alt;
    $largura = ($x>$larguraP) ? $larguraP : $x;
    $altura = ($largura*$y)/$x;

    if($altura>$larguraP){
            $altura = $larguraP;
            $largura = ($altura*$x)/$y;
    }
    $nova = imagecreatetruecolor($largura, $altura);
    imagecopyresampled($nova, $img, 0,0,0,0, $largura, $altura, $x, $y);

    imagejpeg($nova, $pasta.$nome);
    imagedestroy($img);
    imagedestroy($nova);

    return file_exists($pasta.$nome);
}
```

### Sobre os espaçamentos

Neste código:

```
<?php if(!isset($_GET['pagina'])):?>

    <?php
        ob_start();
        session_start();
```

Existem espaços antes do ob_start e session_start, faça assim para evita-los:

```
<?php

if(!isset($_GET['pagina'])):
    ob_start();
    session_start();

    include_once "../../config.php";
    function __autoload($classe){
        require_once "../../classes/".$classe.'.class.php';
    }
    BD::conn();
    $login = new Login('adm_', 'loja_adm');
    $site = new Site;
    $val = new Validacao;

    if(!$login->isLogado()){
        header("Location: ../");
        exit;
    }else{
        $pegar_dados = BD::conn()->prepare("SELECT * FROM `loja_adm` WHERE email_log = ? AND senha_log = ?");
        $pegar_dados->execute(array($_SESSION['adm_emailLog'], $_SESSION['adm_senhaLog']));
        $usuarioLogado = $pegar_dados->fetchObject();
    }
    if(isset($_GET['acao']) && $_GET['acao'] == 'sair'):
        if($login->deslogar()){
            header("Location: ../");
        }
    endif;
    ob_end_flush();
?>
```