# Galeria de Fotos em Miniatura

Tags: php

Tenho o código abaixo, onde o mesmo conecta no banco, pega o nome da imagem e guarda em um Array:

```
while($row = $stm->fetch())  {

echo "<img  src=thumb.php?img=".$row['foto']."/>";

}
```

O arquivo thumb.php, é quem faz todo o tratamento da imagem para deixar em galeria:

```
    $filename = $_GET['img'];
$percent = 0.10;

// Cabeçalho que ira definir a saida da pagina
header('Content-type: image/jpeg');

// pegando as dimensoes reais da imagem, largura e altura
list($width, $height) = getimagesize($filename);

//setando a largura da miniatura
$new_width = 120;
//setando a altura da miniatura
$new_height = 100;

//gerando a a miniatura da imagem
$image_p = imagecreatetruecolor($new_width, $new_height);
$image = imagecreatefromjpeg($filename);
imagecopyresampled($image_p, $image, 0, 0, 0, 0, $new_width, $new_height, $width, $height);

//o 3º argumento é a qualidade da imagem de 0 a 100
imagejpeg($image_p, null, 50);
imagedestroy($image_p);
```

As imagens ficam no mesmo diretorio onde tem o index.php que conecta no banco e mostra a galeria e o arquivo thumb.php.

O problema que não exibe a foto e não gera nenhum erro. Trás os comentários da foto que estão no banco, mas a imagem não.

Comment: Aqui $row['foto'] vem o nome completo da foto em md5, exemplo : 8d399117a184a7f243d236930d60eb0b.png . E no mesmo diretorio existe uma foto com este nome.

Comment: Todos os arquivos, tanto index.php, tanto thumb.php e as imagens estão no mesmo diretorio. De qualquer forma, apontei o diretorio corrente conforme sua sugestão, porem ocorre a mesma situação. nada aparece.

Comment: Fiz este teste e deu falha em abrir arquivo de imagem .png. Criei outro arquivo com o mesmo novo porem em .jpg e agora abriu a tela toda codificada.

Comment: Agora voltei o header e a miniatura abriu diretamente pelo thumb.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A função [**`imagecreatefromjpeg`**](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.imagecreatefromjpeg.php) só lê documentos do tipo JPEG:

```
$image = imagecreatefromjpeg($filename);
```

Arquivos no formato PNG irão causar falha, pois espera uma imagem JPEG.

- Para PNG deve usar [**`imagecreatefrompng`**](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.imagecreatefrompng.php)
- Para GIF deve usar [**`imagecreatefromgif`**](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.imagecreatefromgif.php)
- Para JPEG deve usar [**`imagecreatefromjpeg`**](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.imagecreatefromjpeg.php)

Você pode usar o [**`getimagesize`**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.getimagesize.php) para detectar o tipo da imagem, mas ele não é tão confiável quanto com [**`fileinfo`**](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.fileinfo.php), então baseado nesta outra resposta **https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/73497/3635** ajuste seu código assim:

```
function mimeType($file)
{
    $mimetype = false;

    if (class_exists('finfo')) {//PHP5.4+
        $finfo     = finfo_open(FILEINFO_MIME_TYPE);
        $mimetype  = finfo_file($finfo, $file);
        finfo_close($finfo);
    } else if (function_exists('mime_content_type')) {//php5.3 ou inferiror
        $mimetype = mime_content_type($file);
    }

    return $mimetype;
}

$filename = $_GET['img'];
$percent = 0.10;

//Lê o formato do conteudo da imagem
$mime = mimeType($filename);

if (strpos($mime, 'image/') !== 0) {
    die('Este arquivo não é uma imagem');
}

//Remove o prefixo image/
$mime = substr($mime, 6);

//Remove `x` de x-jpeg, talvez ocorram em alguns servidores antigos
$mime = str_replace('x-', '', $mime);

switch ($mime) {
    case 'jpeg':
        $image = imagecreatefromjpeg($filename);
    break;
    case 'png':
        $image = imagecreatefrompng($filename);
    break;
    case 'gif':
        $image = imagecreatefromgif($filename);
    break;
    default:
        die('Formato não aceito');
}

// Cabeçalho que ira definir a saida da pagina
header('Content-type: image/jpeg');

// pegando as dimensoes reais da imagem, largura e altura
list($width, $height) = getimagesize($filename);

//setando a largura da miniatura
$new_width = 120;
//setando a altura da miniatura
$new_height = 100;

//gerando a a miniatura da imagem
$image_p = imagecreatetruecolor($new_width, $new_height);

imagecopyresampled($image_p, $image, 0, 0, 0, 0, $new_width, $new_height, $width, $height);

//o 3º argumento é a qualidade da imagem de 0 a 100
imagejpeg($image_p, null, 50);
imagedestroy($image_p);
```

Comment: ajustei conforme sua orientação e retorna este erro:   Notice: Undefined variable: file in C:\xampp\htdocs\dashboard\web\web\comprovantes\thumbs\thumbs\thumb.php on line 21

Warning: finfo_file(): Empty filename or path in C:\xampp\htdocs\dashboard\web\web\comprovantes\thumbs\thumbs\thumb.php on line 8
Este arquivo n�o � uma imagem

Comment: @user54154 escrevi o nome da var errado, editei a resposta e corrigi, veja: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/posts/233633/revisions, pode copiar agora.

Comment: Olá Guilherme, boa noite. Agora ele está caindo no case default (('Formato não aceito'); tentei encontrar o erro, mas não consegui. Sou novo em Php.

Comment: @user54154 vou analisar aqui e já lhe aviso

Comment: @user54154 foi erro meu, corrigi agora e testei. Pode copiar novamente e testar ;)

Comment: Agora sim Guilherme. Muito obrigado pelo ajuda. Grande abraço! Pode me indicar algum curso em php, livro, algo que possa me ajudar no meu aprendizado?